# how can ref multi type same time in c#

Tags: c#, ref

I created a master class to be inherited
In the rest of the classes
Added update alert method and at the same time set value
for the property variable
The problem is that I have to add a method for each type
Is there a way to send the variable?
without caring about the type via ref

```
 public class  mainclass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       
           
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       
        public  void NotifyPropertyChange(ref int prop, int value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
          if (prop!=value)
            {
                prop = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

        }

        public void NotifyPropertyChange(ref string prop, string value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
          if (prop != value)
            {
                prop = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

  public class testclass: mainclass
    {
        private int myVar;

        public int MyProperty
        {
            get { return myVar; }
            set => NotifyPropertyChange(ref myVar, value);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with  protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null) ?

Comment: @Serge the problem is that it makes each setter minimum two lines, and more if you want to compare the new value with the previous. This pattern allow single-line setters. Not a huge deal, but it can add up if you have many properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a generic method:

```
private void Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            {
                field = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(caller);
            }
        }
```

Note that it can be problematic to inherit such a base class since .net only allow single inheritance. I usually just copy such a method to ViewModels that need it.